# Where is the location of this swapfile in /etc/fstab

Tags: centos, fstab

[image]

Highlighted in orange is the swap location. But it isn't relative to any path, where is it located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orange text isn't the location, that's identifying the entry as swap. It's located on the logical volume listed before it. You can get more information on that using `lvdisplay`.

Comment: It seems like only swapfiles are the entries that buck the "volume location ..." format?

Comment: Swapfiles aren't mounted as they're not a filesystem, so the word 'swap' is used instead where normally a filesystem would be mounted.

Answer (score 2):

the line look like

```
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap swap defaults 0 0
```

1. the first field identify the device, in this case

   ```
   /dev/mapper/centos-swap
   ```

   the `/dev/mapper` syntax indicate logical volume `swap` on volume group `centos`.
2. second entry `swap` (the one highlighted in orange) is a place holder, second field usualy hold local filesystem entry point (such as `/` or `/var` or `/opt/whatever` )
3. third entry is also `swap`, but indicate option, it can be use to specify, if you have two swaps, priority order, in case of filesystem this field hold mounting option.
4. last two entry (0 and 0 ) are irrevelent for swap, for filesystem they map to mounting order and fsck pass.